# Interoperability advice - Python, C, Matplotlib/OpenGL run-time efficency

Tags: python, c, opengl, interop, python-cffi

Current conditions:

- C code being rewritten to do almost the same type of simulation every time (learning behavior in mice)
- Matlab code being written for every simulation to plot results (2D, potentially 3D graphs)

Here are my goals:

- Design GUI (wxPython) that allows me to build a dynamic simulator
- GUI also displays results of simulation via OpenGL (or perhaps Matplotlib)
- Use a C wrapper (CFFI) to run the simulation and send the results (averages) to OpenGL or Matplotlib

Question:

- In order to have this software run as efficiently as possible, it makes sense to me that CFFI should be used to run the simulation...what I'm not sure about is if it would be better to have that FFI instance (or a separate one?) use an OpenGL C binding to do all the graphics stuff and pass the resulting graphs up to the Python layer to display in the GUI, or have CFFI send the averages of the simulations (the data that gets plotted) to variables in the Python level and use PyOpenGL or Matplotlib to plot graphs.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know what the turnaround time for the simulation runs is and how fast you want to display and update graphs. More or less realtime, tens of milliseconds for each? Seconds? Minutes?

If you want to draw graphs, I'd recommend Matplotlib rather than OpenGL. Even hacking the Matplotlib code yourself to make it do exactly what you want will probably still be easier than doing stuff in OpenGL. And Matplotlib also has "XKCD" style graphs :-)

PyOpenGL works fine with wxPython. Most of the grunt work in modern 3D is done by the GPU so it probably won't be worth doing 3D graphics in C rather than Python if you decide to go that route.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After conferring with a friend about the project design, he suggested to drop the OpenGL aspect as it's too low level and unnecessary for my needs.

Running OSX makes wxPython a huge pain in the ass, so I'm now building the GUI with PySide. I'm gonna start with getting the GUI to open and run previously written C code simulations and their plotted results from previously written MatLab code.

Then I'll work on understanding how to use Matplotlib to read from the C code simulation results to graph based on parameters specified at the GUI level, bypassing the MatLab code.

Comment: Once I've done that, I'll see if there's away to use CFFI to write the C code based on parameters specified at the GUI level, eliminating the need to write C code, unless it's to expand the functionality of the CFFI implementation.

Comment: Also, to address your question about turnaround time:

* the program typically runs 50 simulations of 3 or 4 conditions (loops of 300 trials). Given a condition flag, each trial calls 3 functions that update 5-10 multidimensional arrays (3000 time steps X trial numbers). At the end of each condition (loop of 300 trials) all the averages are computed for the multidimensional arrays and they are written to a file (40-60 files usually).

* with my 2.4 GHz and 4GB, it takes 1m5s to run at 5 simulations, so probably close to 11 minutes at 50 simulations

Comment: Then there's the plotting part which I imagine would be faster with Matplotlib than Octave.

I would like PySide to have mouse and key events for moving 3D graphs and such, but that's a secondary feature for right now